# Outlook 2007: Filter messages differently based on mailing lists

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I am part of two mailing lists, one of which is of high importance to me and should always show up in my Inbox and the other is not so important and should go to a specific folder.
Sometimes both these mailing lists are  in the To/CC list. In this case, I want the message to stay in my Inbox and not get moved. Is this possible with Rules and Alerts ? If not, is there a macro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up 2 rules.

1. those which you want to stay in the inbox, you can add a flag to the message. Ensure you have this one set to "Stop Processing Rules"
2. those which you want to be moved

Ensure that the priotity in the rules list is 1 then 2

That way, if it hits the first rule it will be flagged and stay in the inbox then all other rules will be ignored.